# Is this fall from Firelink Shrine to Valley of Drakes survivable?

Tags: dark-souls

There's a great shortcut (especially if you don't have the [Master Key](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Key)) from Firelink Shrine to Valley of Drakes  which looks like it just might be survivable:

The video is by someone who often shows off stuff in developer mode, and might therefore not be survivable. Is it in fact possible to survive it somehow?

(I would check myself, but I have only a single character which *just* finished the first playthrough, so I'm hoping for independent confirmation.)

Answer (score 3):

This fall is not survivable, normally.

Fall Control does not let you fall further.  It only eliminates the damage if it is a survivable fall <sup>[source](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/fall-damage)</sup>.

However, there is a [Fall Control Exploit](http://speedsouls.com/Fall_Control_Quitout) that can let you survive any fall.  So I guess technically it is survivable, but you're using a glitch.

You're not suppose to survive the fall like the linked video.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to achieve this myself. I have tried with my level 197 character, whom has ~1000 HP. It *might* be achievable through the use of [Fall Control](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/fall-control).

Without knowing the stats of the character in the video, I can't say whether or not this is bugged/hacked/only achievable in dev mode.

Comment: Fall Damage is Dark Souls removes a percentage of your max health, meaning a fall from a deadly height (100% damage) will be deadly for all characters, regardless of the HP amount.

Answer (score 1):

No. Under your normal walkthrough, you will not survive that fall. Also, do not use glitches to your advantage. Play it the hard way, that's the beauty.

PS: Valley of Drakes IMO is really optional.